# Can I customize Tensorflow Serving?

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I am studying Tensorflow Serving. I am not familiar with Tensorflow and have many difficulties, but I am studying through google documents or other documents.

For example, after downloading the Tensorflow Serving source file and then compiling it

```
tensorflow_model_server --port = 9000 --model_name = mnist --model_base_path = / tmp / mnist_model
```

will work normally and communicate with clients using gRPC.

However, should I use tensorflow-serving only with binary files already provided by Google like tensorflow_model_server?

Or can I include the header in C ++ and add it to the library so that I can write the program arbitrarily?

Answer (score 0):

For serving, you can either use the [tensorflow serving C++ API](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_docs/cc), here is some [code example](https://medium.com/@fanzongshaoxing/tensorflow-c-api-to-run-a-object-detection-model-4d5928893b02).

Additionally, Google also provide a docker image that serve the models and expose client API in [RESTful](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest) and [gRPC](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/tree/master/tensorflow_serving/apis) style, so that you can write a client in any languages.

The `tensorflow_model_server` is part of that Dockerized server, and you will need to write your client to interact with it, here are some code examples to make [RESTful](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/resnet_client.py) or [gRPC](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/resnet_client_grpc.py) calls to the server.